# Visual Studio 2015 "non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, visual-studio-2015

I am attempting my own Linked List implementation in C++ and cannot for the life of me figure out why I am having this error. I know there is an STL implementation but for reasons I am trying my own. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class ListElement {
public:
    ListElement(const T &value) : next(NULL), data(value) {}
    ~ListElement() {}

    ListElement *getNext() { return next; }
    const T& value() const { return value; }
    void setNext(ListElement *elem) { next = elem; }
    void setValue(const T& value) { data = value; }

private:
    ListElement* next;
    T data;
};

int main()
{
    ListElement<int> *node = new ListElement<int>(5);
    node->setValue(6);
    std::cout << node->value(); // ERROR
    return 0;
}
```

On the specified line, I get the error "non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member". What the hell does this mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to return the member function `value`, not the member variable `data`. Change

```
const T& value() const { return value; }
```

to

```
const T& value() const { return data; }
```

Comment: @LawrenceAiello Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the confusing combination of templates, multiple meanings of an operator, and a typo.

You have a method returning a `const T&`, where `T` is a template parameter. You intend that to return a constant reference to an object of type `T`. But due to a typo, the compiler thinks you are trying to match that to a method (`value`), rather than an object of type `T` (`data`). The compiler thinks you are trying to use `&` as the pointer-to-member operator, not the reference-to-object operator. But it is smart enough that something is not quite right, and so gives a warning.