# non-standard syntax use '&' to create a pointer to member c++

Tags: c++

I have created two vectors `o3` ( a vector to hold the words from a string) and `o4 ( a vector to hold those vector of words). In the if statement, once ";" has been found in the vector`o3[i]`, I want to stop putting words from that`o3[i]` into o4, and go to the next line held in o3. I am getting the error "non-standard syntax use '&' to create a pointer to member c++" in the line commented as ERROR. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
    while (getline(myfile, line, (char)32)) // first read entire line into a 
                                            //string
                                  // problem : this also reads empty lines 
                                 // and gives error 
                                  // while returning words
    {
        abc2.push_back(line); // inserting individual strings into a vector
                             //cout << abc[i] << "\n"; // use this to see 
                             // them as a vector of lines
                             //i++;

    }
 for (int i = 0; i < abc.size(); i++)
    {
        single_line = abc[i];
        if (((single_line[0] >= 'A') && (single_line[0] <= 'Z')) || 
         ((single_line[0] >= 'a') && (single_line[0] <= 'z')))
        {

            if (abc[i] != "")
            {

                o3 = output_words(abc[i], (char)32); // function to separate 
                                                     //words in a line
                int j1 = 0; int j2 = 0;
                while (j2 < o3.size())
                {
                    if (o3[j2] != "" && "\t") // *IMP* require this line to 
                                               // get words
                                              // irrespective of spaces
                    {
                        if (o3[j2].find != ";") // ERROR
                        {
                            o4.resize(i + 1);// NO CLUE WHY IT WORKED WITH 
                                             // i+1 resize???!!!
                            o4[i].push_back(o3[j2]);
                            j2++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            j2++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        j2++;
                    }
                }

            }


        }
            else
            {
                o3 = { "" }; // o1 will be null vector (i.e will contain 
                             // nothing inside)
                o4.push_back(o3);
            }


        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: You probably meant `if (o3[j2].find(';') == std::string::npos)` or some variation thereof. Explain what it is you want to find, and what you plan to do with it once found or not found.

Comment: How subject of this question is related?

Comment: @Slava `o3[j2].find` produces an error message with wording similar to that of the subject. The compiler (MSVC, I'm pretty sure) thinks this might be a botched attempt to take an address of `find` member function.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik why do think OP is going to bother to explain it to you?

Comment: @Slava Well, they would if they want advice on fixing the problem. If they don't bother to explain, then I don't bother to give further advice. So it's kind of in their best interest, but if they won't, I'm not going to shed any tears.

Comment: @BoPersson right, they should make a plugin for VS that redirects any compilation error directly to SO. It is pity that OP has to copy paste them here.

Comment: Thank you. I have just used c++ for a month now. I put a parameter in find(";") and it worked!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 "non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062632/visual-studio-2015-non-standard-syntax-use-to-create-a-pointer-to-member)

Answer (score 1):

The result of expression `o3[j2].find` is a member of `o3[j2]` by the name `find`. That result is then compared with the string literal in the full expression `o3[j2].find != ";"`.

The warning message seems to imply, that `decltype(o3[j2])::find` is a member function. In this context, the name of the member function decays to a member function pointer. The compiler warns you because such implicit conversion is ill-formed according to the standard, but supported as a language extension by the compiler. The standard way is to use the address-of operator `&` explicitly.

Comparing (a pointer to) a member function to a string literal makes little sense. You may have intended to call the member function instead. To call a function, you add the argument list surrounded by parenthesis: `o3[j2].find(/* arguments */)`.

Assuming `decltype(o3[j2])` is `std::string` (you forgot to declare `o3`), then the comparison with string literal also seems suspicious. `std::string::find` returns the index of the found substring or character. Comparing an integer to a string literal doesn't make any sense either. I recommend pondering what that line is supposed to do.